# How to create a new top level environment in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I would like to pass user input to `eval`. Therefor I would like to create a new top level environment. Is this possible in any browser?

Comment: By "a new top level environment", do you mean to somehow sandbox the user code so they don't have access to the existing global scope? If so, check out web workers.

Comment: I interpreted a "new top level environment" to mean a new browser window.

Comment: @Amy I do not need a second browser. Just a secure evaluation environment for computations.

Comment: please tell us what you mean with top level environment. or maybe tell us what you try to achive? I do not reccomand using `eval` at all ... so maybe there is an other aproach then yours for the problem ...

Comment: @helle A top level environment is the global environment where evaluation takes place. JavaScripts mother Scheme has some operations to work on [top level environments](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Top_002dlevel-Environments.html). So I thought JavaScript might have something similar.